# custom unfold returning the accumulator

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tail-recursion, unfold

I'm trying to create a custom unfold function that returns its last accumulator value like:

```
val unfold' : generator:('State -> ('T * 'State) option) -> state:'State -> 'T list * 'State
```

I managed to make the following:

```
let unfold' generator state =
    let rec loop resultList state =
        match generator state with
        | Some (value, state) -> loop (value :: resultList) state
        | None -> (List.rev resultList), state
    loop [] state
```

But I wanted to avoid to `List.rev` the resulting list and generate it already with the correct order. I imagine it would be necessary to use continuations to build the list, but I'm quite new to functional programming and have not yet managed to wrap my mind around continuations; and all alternatives I can imagine would put the accumulator inside the resulting list or not allow it to be returned by the function.

Is there some way to do this?

As this is a personal learning exercise I would prefer an answer explaining how to do it instead of simply giving the completed code.

Comment: Continuation is the way to go (if you really want to avoid that somehow *harmless* `List.rev`). A continuation is *just* a function which will build the result (here a list). Not sure how an answer not giving the answer (the code) could be though.

Comment: I know that ```List.rev``` is harmless, I'm just trying to learn how to do without. Code is welcome, I just would prefer an explanation that would allow me to do it myself as much as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do without a `List.rev` is to pass a function instead of the `resultList` parameter. Let's call that function `buildResultList`. At each step, this function would take the already-built tail of the list, prepend the current item, and then pass this to the function from the *previous* step, which would append the *previous* item, pass it to the function from the *previous-previous* step, and so on. The very last function in this chain will prepend the very first item to the list. The result of the whole recursive loop would be the *last* function of the chain (it calls all the previous ones), which you would then call with empty list as argument. I'm afraid this is as clear as I can go without just writing the code.

**However**, the thing is, this wouldn't be any better, for any definition of "better". Since the computation is progressing "forward", and resulting list is built "backward" (head :: tail, Lisp-style), you *have* to accumulate the result *somewhere*. In your code, you're accumulating it in a temporary list, but if you modify it to use continuations, you'll be accumulating it on the heap as a series of closures that reference each other in a chain. One could argue that it would be, in essence, the same list, only obfuscated.

Another approach you could try is to use a lazy sequence instead: build a recursive `seq` computation, which will `yield` the current item and then `yield!` itself. You can then enumerate this sequence, and it won't require a "temporary" storage. **However**, if you still want to get a list at the end, you'll have to convert the sequence to a list via `List.ofSeq`, and guess how that's going to be implemented? Theoretically, from purely mathematical standpoint, `List.ofSeq` would be implemented in exactly the same way: by building a temp list first and then reversing it. But the F# library cheats here: it builds the list in a mutable way, so it doesn't have to reverse.

And finally, since this is a learning exercise, you could also implement the equivalent of a lazy sequence yourself. Now, the standard .NET sequences (aka `IEnumerable<_>`, which is what `Seq<_>` is an alias for) are inherently *mutable*: you're changing the internal state of the iterator every time you move to the next item. You can do that, or, in the spirit of learning, you can do an immutable equivalent. That would be *almost* like a list (i.e. head::tail), except that, since it's *lazy*, the "tail" has to be a promise rather than the actual sequence, so:

```
type LazySeq<'t> = LazySeq of (unit -> LazySeqStep<'t>)
and LazySeqStep<'t> = Empty | Cons of head: 't * tail: LazySeq<'t>
```

The way to enumerate is to invoke the function, and it will return you the next item plus the tail of the sequence. Then you can write your unfold as a function that returns current item as `head` and then just returns itself wrapped in a closure as `tail`. Turns out pretty simple, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Fyodor Soikin's answer, here is the resulting function:

```
let unfold' generator state =
    let rec loop build state =
        match generator state with
        | Some (value, state) -> loop (fun newValue -> build (value :: newValue)) state
        | None -> (build []), state
    loop id state
```